# How to install windows 10 from flash drive, and overwrite CRASHED version of linux?

Tags: windows, delete, reinstall

I have a compaq presario CQ60
With a CRASHED version of Ubuntu Linux,
I am not knowledgeable on how to use linux to begin with, let alone fix a computer that keeps repeating " [sdb] asking for cache data failed"
And a never ending repeat of it saying 
"[sdb] assuming drive cache: write through"
Then it hit repeating the asking for cache failed, over and over and over again, the owner before me said this OS is completely crashed, it doesn't load, it goes to the purple page showing Ubuntu and the 4 dots lighting up then immediately goes to a black screen repeating that, I've attached an image showing.
I have used another computer to download windows 10 (sigh) onto a flash drive, and I want to install it on this laptop and not have any trace of linux on here, how do I do so?? Like I said it does not give me the option to type or do anything, it's def screwed up..

Comment: It deleted my photo but it's just a black screen showing what I said over and over again never ending

Comment: This question would be better asked in http://superuser.com, as it's not related to Ubuntu, but Windows and it's booting/installation.

Answer (score 0):

Create bootable USB of Windows 10 and shutdown your system and then choose USB from Boot Manager and then installation process will start as usual.